# Get data from User table without current user

Tags: swift, parse-platform, swift2

I'm trying to get all the user's from the `_User` table and get their images and put them into an array. The below code works when I am logged in (current user != nil)

but when I'm not logged in (current user = nil) I get no images at all

How can i achive this query without being a current user ???

I have the following function

```
 let chefUserQuery = PFQuery(className: "_User")
        chefUserQuery .whereKey("chef", equalTo: true)
        chefUserQuery .findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
            (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                 if let objects = objects as? [PFUser] {
                        var ai = 0
                        for object in objects {
                            print("kati")
                            let imageChef = object["avatar"] as! PFFile


                               imageChef.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (data, error) -> Void in
                                    if error == nil {
                                        if let imageData = data {
                                            let imagatzaki = UIImage(data: imageData)
                                            let idChef = object.objectId
                                            self.imagesOfChef[ai] = chefImages(objidChef: idChef, imageChef: imagatzaki)
                                            ai += 1

                                            print(self.imagesOfChef)

                                } } })

                        }
                    completion(.Success())
                }

            }
            else {
                // Log details of the failure
                print("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo)")

            }
        }
```

Thanks

Comment: is `chef` related to current user?

Comment: @ÖzgürErsil `chef` is a collumn inside `User` table which has  a true false value.

Comment: then better use  `PFUser.enableAutomaticUser()` in app delegate for anonymous

Comment: @ÖzgürErsil in my case this is not a proper solution (I tried it) and it crashes in many other things that require current user and if its nil i get them to another view (login) although the main content that i want to show require and the images of each chef. Anyway i will try another query

Comment: @ÖzgürErsil actually i get the results of the query but the table is not filled out with images inside the `imageChef.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (data, error)` any idea why?

Comment: let imageChef = object["avatar"] as! PFFile isn't a url of the image?

Comment: the URL is available as a property of PFFile so you can access the PFFile URL like this: 

 
let imageChef = object["avatar"] as! PFFile
imageChef.url!